# How to get airports with iata code in Google Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete

Can Anyone tell me how can we pass airport into below url:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(regions)&language=in&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Type Allowed:

1. geocode
2. address
3. establishment
4. (regions)
5. (cities)

Because when I a calling below URLs I met with errors:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(airport)&language=in&key=YOUR_API_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=airport&language=in&key=YOUR_API_KEY

After some research, I got to know **Types supported in place search and addition** has airport type but  **Types supported in place autocomplete requests** don't have airport type.